# is it possible to build an "auto clicker" via powershell for windows, or green software?

Tags: windows, powershell, open-source, automation, greensoftware

i'd like to automate some processes, basically run some tools, click the menu, select from dropdownlist, then copy and paste to a notepad.exe application to save as a txt file -- all in windows.

however my company environment probably won't allow installation.

so i'm wondering, if it's possible to write a powershell script for that?

or, if there's any green software that needs no instalation? best if it's open-sourced.

Comment: could u -- who voted to close this question -- please comment how to improve the question? it's a real problem i met in my work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of what you really want to do, there is a Windows Automation Snapin ([WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/)) for PowerShell. Some usage examples [here](http://wasp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Some%20Usage%20Examples&referringTitle=Home). I've used it myself for simple tasks and it works quite well.

Comment: thanks, let me check it out. btw, love the name WASP :p

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for
>   automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a
>   combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control
>   manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or
>   reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is
>   also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of
>   Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

Also you can generate executables of your scripts:

> Scripts can be compiled into standalone executables